# Kubernetes EnvoyFilter description

Tags: kubernetes, filter, istio, envoyproxy

I have to check is any EnvoyFilter is deployed in kubernetes with istio, how can we find it in kubernetes dashboard or using kubectl command.

Answer (score 3):

This should work
`kubectl get envoyfilter`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can´t check it with either kubectl or kubernetes dashboard, it´s enabled by default as it´s just configuring envoy, which istio is based on.

I would say the easiest way to actually check if it´s deployed with istio is to create some simple envoy filter and try it. There are few examples in below documentation and in the tutorial.

As mentioned [there](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/#envoy) and [there](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/envoy-wasm-filter/)

> **Istio uses an extended version of the Envoy proxy**. Envoy is a high-performance proxy developed in C++ to mediate all inbound and outbound traffic for all services in the service mesh. Envoy proxies are the only Istio components that interact with data plane traffic.

> Envoy is a high performance, programmable L3/L4 and L7 proxy that many service mesh implementations, such as **Istio**, are based on. At the core of Envoy's connection and traffic handling are network filters, which, once mixed into filter chains, allow the implementation of higher-order functionalities for access control, transformation, data enrichment, auditing, and so on. **You can add new filters to extend Envoy's current feature set with new functionalities**.

As mentioned in documentation [there](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/)

> EnvoyFilter provides a mechanism to **customize the Envoy configuration generated by Istio Pilot**. **Use EnvoyFilter to modify values for certain fields, add specific filters**, or even add entirely new listeners, clusters, etc.

Additionally take a look at this [tutorial](https://dev.to/aurelievache/understanding-istio-part-12-envoyfilter-4hf2).